# Can you filter file search based on folder names?

Tags: powershell

I'm pretty sure I got it right, but want to double check with community.
I have a folder structure that starts, say from `c:\test\` it has many files and folders. I also have a folder in this structure, say `c:\test\something\another\temp\` this folder and its subfolders account for about 50% or more of all the files in `c:\test\`.

I want to get a list of all `*.txt` files in `c:\test\` and its subfolders, excluding those, that are in `c:\test\something\another\temp\` and deeper.

I don not want to enumerate the whole thing including `c:\test\something\another\temp\` and then pipe out and filter for performance reason: there is just no need to walk through the whole `c:\test\something\another\temp\` tree, since there is nothing of interest there.

It does not look like `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet can help me here, I have to resort to .NET calls and write the recursion myself to exclude the folder I don't need.

`Get-ChildItem` has `-Exclude` parameter but it does not work on folders, only on files.

I'm fine with calling .NET library I'll just want to make sure I'm not missing anything and there is no <easier> way to do this with stock powershell cmdlets.

Is there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the directory is really large,

```
(cmd /c dir c:\test\*.txt /b /s) -notlike 'c:\test\something\another\temp\*'
```

should give you much quicker results than get-childitem.

Edit:

Here a different version that doesn't search the excluded directories:

```
$files = 
(cmd /c dir c:\test /b /s /ad) -notlike 'c:\test\something\another\temp*' |
 foreach { iex "cmd /c dir $_\*.txt /b /s /a-d"  }
```

Don't know how to get it any quicker than that.

Comment: This is decent route to go.  On my tests it took about 5.5 secs on my test dir for the cmd dir and 10 seconds using my solution.  Note: using gci -exclude is slower (18 secs) than filter using Where {}.  And IMO, going through the trouble to write a recursive function to do this just isn't worth it when you can get cmd dir to do the heavy lifting.  Oh yeah, pretty much all the time (10 secs) is taken by GCI.  The filtering using Where {} adds very little to the overall the time.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could do:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\test -r *.txt | Where {$_.FullName -notlike 'c:\test\something\another\temp\*'}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this traverse the entire tree instead of skipping child folders/files when the path is a match?

Comment: Yup.  Missed the bit about not wanting to enumerate the excluded dirs.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating your own function which recursively calls itself, skipping the directory you don't want to look at. I think it's doing what you're envisioning in your mind, but just with built-in cmdlets instead of resorting to .NET Framework methods.

```
$searchroot = 'c:\test';
function Get-FilesInDir {
param (
    $DirToSearch
)
    $ItemsInDir = Get-ChildItem -path $DirToSearch;
    foreach ($item in $ItemsInDir) {
        if ($item.FullName -eq 'c:\test\something\another\temp') {
            continue;
        }
        if ($item.PSIsContainer) {
            Get-FilesInDir $item.FullName;
        }
        $item.FullName;
    }
}

Get-FilesInDir $searchroot
```

This will output the full path to each file found.

If you have a list of directories you want to exclude, you can put them into an array and modify the `if` test around the `continue` to check each path to see if it's in that array.

Answer (score 0):

Another option utilizing the pipeline:

```
function Get-FilesInDir {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        $Path,
        $Exclude
    )

    Process {
        $Path | ForEach-Object {
            if( (Resolve-path $_).Path.StartsWith($Exclude) ) { return }

            Get-ChildItem -Path:$_ |
                ForEach-Object { 
                    if($_.PSIsContainer) { Get-FilesInDir -Path:$_.FullName -Exclude:$Exclude }
                    $_.FullName
                }
        }
    }
}
```